# When game is focused somehow my music and browser audio is lowered, any ideas?

Tags: steam

Somehow whenever I'm playing any game on Steam (any game, including WoWs, Satisfactory, and Cities Skylines) if i have the game focused (i'm in game), somehow my machine is lowering my audio for my browser and also lowering iTunes. I've also noticed that when in game the itunes music and browser has less EQ. i.e. Little to no bass.

I have currently disabled the communications under Control Panel -> Sound -> Communications -> Disabled

I'm also running VoiceMeeter, however this issue was happening prior to the installation of that software, so I'm assuming that this is either a Windows issue or a Steam issue. I've looked and found numerous articles and other answers on forums, however they are all about 6 years old, and no solution is applicable here as the information contained within is outdated.

Is anyone else having these issues, or knows whats going on?

Comment: Which browser are you using, just out of curiosity?

Comment: Also, with "disabled the communications" you mean the "When Windows detects communications activity" tab set as "Do nothing"? (There is no "Disabled" option, only Mute, 80%, 50% and Do nothing)

Comment: Google Chrome updated to the latest version. But this is also happening with iTunes as well, not just the browser. Yea. Do Nothing. Sorry.